# access to a tomcat from internet (security terms)

Tags: security, tomcat

I have a tomcat 6.0.32 running in a ubuntu server 12.
It's used in a local enviroment, I mean, only in the private network where is hosted.

This tomcat runs an application developed in JSF using PrimeFaces 3.3.
Now, they want to have access from the outside of the enterprise, I mean, from Internet.

So my question is, What's the best way to do that (in security terms)?.. having another tomcat that publishes to the internet and communicates with the other tomcat who has the application ? it is that possible ? or what is the best solution ?

Thanks for any tip or help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this (in security terms), is to leave the Tomcat server running on the local network, but provide VPN access to the network.  This way others can access the server from the internet if they're connected via VPN, but not just everyone will be able to access it.

That being said, is there a reason you are worried about externally facing your Tomcat?  As long as your Tomcat and the host OS are both fully patched, you should be OK unless your web app itself has vulnerabilities.  Keep those patches up to date though!

If you're worried about the security of your web app, you should probably consider hiring a professional penetration tester to take a look at things for you.  That can be really expensive, so before you do that scan your app with some scanners like [w3af](http://w3af.org/), [Wapiti](http://wapiti.sourceforge.net/), [Nikto](http://cirt.net/nikto2), and [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/).  Fix vulnerabilities that they find so the pen tester can find the really hard stuff :-)